# Как избежать повторной отправки формы при перезагрузке страницы?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Столкнулся с проблемой повторного добавления данных формы в базу данных при перезагрузке страницы.

- Добавляю данные через форму
- Страница перезагружается, данные записываются в бд и выводятся куда нужно
- Но при повторной перезагрузке выдает ошибку confirm form resubmission

[image: такая ошибка]

Код страницы с формой - тут форма которая открывается в попапе, слайдер в который выводятся результаты формы, подключение скрипта для записи данных в бд и скрипт для вывода данных из бд:

```
<?php include_once("testimonials.php") ?>

<div class="hidden" id="bookTraining-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="bookTraining-modalLabel">
    <form id="feedback-form" class="bookTraining-modal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p class="bookTraining-modal__heading">Write your feedback</p>
        <p class="bookTraining-modal__text">Your name:</p><br>
        <input class="bookTraining-modal__input" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off"><br>
        <p class="bookTraining-modal__text">Feedback:</p><br>
        <textarea class="bookTraining-modal__input feedback-textarea" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="feedback" id="feedback" tabindex="4" maxlength="500" autocomplete="off"></textarea><br>
        <input class="bookTraining-modal__sendButton" type="submit" name="send" value="Send" action="testimonials.php">
    </form>
</div>

<div class="feedbacks-slider">
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "");
    $connectedDe = mysql_select_db('wptest');
    if(!$connection || $connectedDe){
        mysql_error();
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testimonials");
    mysql_close();

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $start_limit = 0;
    $limit = 6;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
        <div class="feedback">
            <div class="feedback-content">
                <p class="feedback-heading"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></p>
                <p class="feedback-text"><?php echo $row['feedback'] ?></p>
                <a href="#feedback-form" class="feedback-link">LEAVE YOUR FEEDBACK</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Код записи данных в бд через форму (в отдельном файле testimonials.php):

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "");
$connectedDe = mysql_select_db('wptest');
if(!$connection || $connectedDe){
    mysql_error();
}

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $feedback = $_POST['feedback'];

    mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO testimonials (name, feedback)
        VALUES ('$name', '$feedback')
    ");

    mysql_close();

}?>
```

Необходимо открывать форму в попапе и обрабатывать на той же странице.

Пробовал так (этот код вставлял сразу после подключения скрипта добавления через форму):

```
<?php header('Location: index.php');
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at W:\domains\wptest\wp-content\themes\personal_trainer\header.php:4) in W:\domains\wptest\wp-content\themes\personal_trainer\index.php on line 149

Как я понимаю нужно сделать редирект на эту же страницу и\или исключить кеширование данных формы браузером.

Comment: Сделайте так, что бы скрипт добавления не пытался ничего выводить на страницу, тогда Location сработает. т.е. он должен быть первым выводом чего либо. Еще убедитесь что в начале php файла нет BOM (он не видим в обычном редакторе)

Answer (score -1):

Посмотрите на файл `header.php:4`

Из вашего сообщения непонятно что это за файл, но предположу что так происходит потому что вы делаете шаблонные вставки

Например:

`<?php include_once("testimonials.php"); ?>
 <?php header('Location: index.php'); ?>`

Означает:

1. Подключи testimonials.php
2. Т.к. скобка интерпретатора закрывается `?>` после нее посылаем вывод без преобразования до следующей скобки интерпретатора `<?php`
3. Пробуем послать заголовки, но они уже отправлены **перед выводом страницы**
4. Скобка закрылась, выводи далее `<div class="hidden" id="bookTraining-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="bookTraining-modalLabel">`
    и т.д.

По-хорошему делайте редирект сразу после записи в БД. 
И до этого не должно никакого вывод. Ранее правильно писали, проверьте нет ли BOM меток или пробелов в вашем файле.

И еще пару советов:

1. Вместо функций `mysql_*` используйте `mysqli_`, тк первые удалены в PHP7
2. Очищайте/экранируйте пользовательский ввод $_POST перед вставкой с помощью [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string), `(int)`, [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php), а лучше почитайте про [Подготовленные выражения](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php)